# Having a flex content confined inside its parent

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex layout as created in here - https://jsfiddle.net/7t1m0gL2/13/

The problem being, the long text goes beyond its parent to occupy further space even if `overflow: hidden` etc. are provided.

```css
.left {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 0; 
}

.profile {
  padding: 5px 0;  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}  


.image {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}  
      
.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
      
.name {
  color: red;
}

.description {
  color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="master">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="profile">
      <div class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="name">
          Some short name
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          Some very long description that's most likely to overflow here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` to `.text`: https://jsfiddle.net/7t1m0gL2/25/

Comment: overflow:hidden should be set on the flex parent , since you are using flex, the parent is holding the content, and children are just layed in it  and can overflow. (duplicate linked tells you about it)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a class of `overflow: hidden` to your `.text` element. The inner element is not aware of the width of its parent, therefore you need to set the overflow property on the element containing the element that needs to be truncated.

```css
.left {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 0; 
}

.profile {
  padding: 5px 0;  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}  


.image {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}  
      
.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
      
.name {
  color: red;
}

.description {
  color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="master">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="profile">
      <div class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="name">
          Some short name
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          Some very long description that's most likely to overflow here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but you may want to consider providing an explanation.